# Why can't I get latitude and longitude using getBounds function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var map;

function initialize(location) {

var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(14.457264, 121.024038);
var mapOptions = {
  center: currentPosition,
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions)

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: currentPosition,
  map: map,
  icon: "../images/02_button_add.png"
});

var bounds = map.getBounds();
alert(bounds);
}
```

Above is my code, I can have my current position on map.
However, the getBounds function is not working when trying to alert with information,it gives "undefined" value as a result.

Is anything wrong?

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps getBounds() returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555582/google-maps-getbounds-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a listener in order for your getBounds() to display correctly

I suggest this code **(EDIT)**:

```
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){

   var bounds = map.getBounds();
   alert(bounds);
});
```

Here is your fiddle so you can test it (after it loads click run again): http://jsfiddle.net/vA4eQ/280/

Comment: Thanks. But how to getBounds after map initialise without bounds_changed event?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google documentation,

> getBounds()
>
> Return Value:  LatLngBounds
>   Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If more than one copy of the world is visible, the bounds range in longitude from -180 to 180 degrees inclusive. *If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the result is null or undefined.*

Hence you must first initialize your map.