# TypeError: map is undefined google api

Tags: javascript

I have been referencing a found tutorial and have stumbled upon an error using the google maps api. I am getting and error that telling me that a variable is not defined when in fact it is. I am not exactly sure what the problem is.. Please help.

```
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true">
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var service;

    function handleSearchResults (results, status)
    {
         console.log(results);
    }
    function performSearch ()
    {
        var request = {
            bounds: map.getBounds(),
            name: "McDonald's" // within the bounds find the given name
        }
        service.nearbySearch(request, handleSearchResults);
    }

    function initialize (location) //initializing geolocation function
    {
            console.log(location);

        var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
            var mapOptions = {
                center: currentLocation,
                zoom: 13
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);
                // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: currentLocation,
                map: map // referencing google map from variable map above
             });

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      // wait until map bounds are initialized before performing search
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);
    }

    $( document ).ready(function()
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);  

    });

    </script>





</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're not ever calling your `initialize` function

Comment: Well yes initialize was called within $(document).ready(function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running into scoping issues with that map variable since you're calling the `initialize` function from within the scope of the `$(document.ready()` callback. I made some adjustments to it in the jsfiddle below. Does that fix the issue?

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu6gt/6/)**</kbd>

```
function handleSearchResults (results, status)
{
    console.log(results);
}

function performSearch ()
{
    var request = {
        bounds: map.getBounds(),
        name: "McDonald's" // within the bounds find the given name
    }
    service.nearbySearch(request, handleSearchResults);
}

function initialize (location) //initializing geolocation function
{
    console.log(location);

    var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
    var mapOptions = {
        center: currentLocation,
        zoom: 13
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                              mapOptions);
    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentLocation,
        map: map // referencing google map from variable map above
    });

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    // wait until map bounds are initialized before performing search
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);
}   

$(document).ready(function() {
    var map;
    var service;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);    
})
```

Comment: I just didn't include that part because stackoverflow was fussing about to much code vs. explanation

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Is this the same error you're running into by chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832636/google-maps-api-v3-getbounds-is-undefined?rq=1

Comment: Umm not quite...I have handled that issue with the google maps event listener. I am getting a different issue pertaining to the variable named map

Comment: Ahh, okay. I think the issue is that you're within the scope of the $(document).ready function. When map is referenced in the callback, it's not within that scope anymore so its undefined.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Let me know if that does the trick.

Comment: Ah nice..so to remedy that issue you just included all functions within the scope of the $(document).ready function..is that your logic in solving this? Could I have also added the handleSearchResults function within to the $(document).ready function?

Comment: Right, it's actually not necessary to have all the functions wrapped in the scope of `document.ready` though, I think you just need to have the `map` variable in the same scope. Another solution would be doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qu6gt/6/