# show loading image while loading google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API for showing a map in my site with aditional markers. This is the trigger

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
```

This works fine, but the map takes a few seconds to show. I'm putting a loading image in the map div like this:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:500px"><img src="/image/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
```

But the image never shows, just the blank page until the map shows.

The image is working, because if I disable the map loading function, the image is there. 
So I think the google map clears the div before the map is loaded.

Any ideas how to show a loading feedback to the user while waiting? I could not find a function in the API...

Comment: I thinks is is a duplicate question. There are answers vor the API v2 and v3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692

Comment: I dont think is duplicated, I edited my question so it doesn't seems duplicated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might try to wrap the map div inside another div, and set the containing div's background to have some sort of animation graphic. Generally I've found that it's not a good idea to manipulate or place anything inside the element that Google Maps uses as the map.

Comment: Ok, this worked: (the map goes in "map_canvas")
`
<div style="width:700px; height:500px; "><img  src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:500px; top:-25px;"></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 28):

It's easier to add a GIF via CSS to the background of the Map DIV.

i.e.

html

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

css

```
#map_canvas {background: transparent url(images/ajax-loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
```

the loading GIF will stay visible until the map is loaded.  Very handy if your using the sensor to get the current location, as this takes a while. As soon as google maps is ready to populate #map_canvas with it's own images, you won't be able to see the loading GIF any more.