# Show loading status during loading of a GeoJSON using Gmaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

How can I intercept the loading of a GeoJSON using `loadGeojson` function Gmaps ? I'm carrying a gejson of MultiLineString but takes a few seconds to appear on the screen and I need to add a loading for the user to wait for charging

```
function load(){
  google.maps.event.addListener(myLayer, 'addfeature', function (e) {
    map.setCenter(e.feature.getGeometry().getAt(0).getAt(0));
  });       

  myLayer.loadGeoJson("/data/myLayer.json");
  myLayer.setMap(map); 

  myLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {  
   return {
      strokeColor: "#B00000",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,  
      strokeWeight: 4  
    };
  });
}
```

---

Ivan your answer was the solution to my problem. Thank you! But still have a doubt only works when I create a new map object:

```
  ......
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  cicloviasLayer.setMap(map);
```

I do not want to create a new map but plot in an existing map, how do I get the loading run in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941034/1023562):

Use CSS to add loading `giff` image:

```
#map_canvas {background: transparent url(images/ajax-loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
```

It will dissappear once map is loaded, as shown in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pummurrg/1/).

Comment: Ivan  I need more information sbore the loading on a map object existing, I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), you'll see that loadGeoJson has a callback function as the third parameter. So you can show a spinner before the call to loadGeoJson and hide it right after the callback is invoked.