# How to check if Google Maps API is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to check if Google Maps API (v3) is loaded?

I do not want to execute mapping scripts if the API did not load due to internet connectivity problems (web page is hosted locally).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`if (google.maps) {...}` will give you a reference error if google is undefined (i.e. if the API didn't load).

Instead, use `if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {...}` to check if it loaded successfully.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have been looking for.

Comment: I'm in a namespaced environment, so simply referencing `google` didn't work for me, I had to use `window.google`.

Comment: I believe there are cases were `google.maps` may be defined before the Maps API has entirely finished loading, causing this to break inconsistently.  If anyone else has the same issue, may want to try my answer below, using a callback.

Comment: It gives me error google is undefined. Why is it that?

Comment: Daniela, what's the code you're using to check if google is defined? The typeof operator I suggested shouldn't give a "google is undefined" error.

Answer (score 30):

None of the current answers are working with 100% consistency for me (excluding Google Loader, which I haven't tried). I don't think checking the existence of `google.maps` is enough to be sure the library has finished loading. Here are the network requests I'm seeing when the Maps API and optional Places library are requested:

[image: maps api network requests]

That very first script defines `google.maps`, but the code that you probably need (`google.maps.Map`, `google.maps.places`) won't be around until some of the other scripts have loaded.

It is much safer to define a callback when loading the Maps API. @verti's answer is almost correct, but still relies on checking `google.maps` unsafely.

Instead, do this:

HTML:

```
<!-- "async" and "defer" are optional, but help the page load faster. -->
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=mapsCallback">
</script>
```

JS:

```
var isMapsApiLoaded = false;
window.mapsCallback = function () {
  isMapsApiLoaded = true;
  // initialize map, etc.
};
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine nowadays, if you don't have to support older versions of IE (<9).

Answer (score 14):

in async loading this one works for me (Thanks to DaveS) :

```
   function appendBootstrap() {
    if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
        handleApiReady();
    } else {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=handleApiReady";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}

function handleApiReady() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.51728, 34.765211);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/)

```
google.load("maps", "3", {callback: myFn});
```

It will load your designated javascript file, then execute the callback, specified in the `optionalSettings` argument.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my issue because the loader script itself has to be loaded from the internet. If the connection fails, `google.load` will throw a reference error. Nevertheless appreciate your response.

Comment: The Google maps API isn't part of the available APIs according to that page.

Comment: The answer dates back to Feb 2012. The loader API might have changed since then.

Comment: The Google Loader link above is now completely gone

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
If you are not afraid to be "not explicit" then you can use following, otherwise if you are not sure if there will be only one instance of `google` variable then use DaveS answer.

Check if google maps v3 api loaded:

```
if(google && google.maps){
    console.log('Google maps loaded');
}
```

in this condition variable `google` will use javascript truth so if it will be function or object or string it will become true and then will try to access `maps` inside of that object.

And inverse:

```
if(!google || !google.maps){
    console.log('Not loaded yet');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, there's an issue with the accepted answer.
It will return true if the script has loaded otherwise **'typeof google' may return undefined and throw an error**. The solution to this is:

`if ('google' in window && typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {...}`

This makes sure a boolean value is always returned.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if(google && google.maps)` check didn't work for me; I still get an error when I try to access the API:

> TypeError: google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor

In my case this is probably due to my mouse event handlers being triggered before the maps API has even finished downloading. In this case, to reliably check if maps is loaded, I create a "gmaps" alias and initialise it on dom ready (using JQuery):

```
var gmaps;
$(function () {
    gmaps = google.maps;
});
```

then in my event handlers I can simply use:

```
if(gmaps) {
    // do stuff with maps
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**try**

```
(google && 'maps' in google)?true:false
```

**or**

```
if(google && 'maps' in google){
    //true
}
else{
    //false
}
```

**since** I had a **problem** with the following on mobile:

```
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with an `if(google && google.maps){ … }`, unless you mean what is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692/how-to-check-if-google-maps-is-fully-loaded), which is about Maps API V2, but someone updated it for v3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050796/1202204).

Comment: `if (google.maps) {...}` threw me an error when the API was not loaded. DaveS has addressed the issue in his answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery`, I have good news for you:

```
if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {
     gmapInit();
} else {
     $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+gApiKey+'&language=en', function(){
         gmapInit();
     });
 }
```

it's similar to [answer-17702802](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228958/how-to-check-if-google-maps-api-is-loaded#answer-17702802)