# Is there a way to know if a tile of a overlay layer failed to load in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262773/981427) answer, but the 'idle' event gets fired even if some tiles failed to load, Is there a way to know if a tile of a overlay layer failed to load in google maps?