# jQuery Gmap3: where is the success callback?

Tags: jquery-gmap3

I would like to know when my gmap is loaded. I didn't see any callback method in the documentation and around the web.

I'm using this plugin: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/

Any tip? Thx

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to revert and use the google maps native function.  The answer toyour question is outlined in this question: [How can I check whether Google Maps is fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692/how-to-check-if-google-maps-is-fully-loaded)

and it looks like the best answer is given with this code snippet:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // do something only the first time the map is loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem to be documented but there is a callback property on the map object

```
  $('#map_canvas').gmap3(
  {
    map: {
      options: {
        zoom: 9,
        center: [view.lat, view.lng]
      },
      callback: function (e) {
         alert("loaded");
      }
    }
  });
```