# How to execute helper function after DOM is ready in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of `<li>`'s which gets populated with a find() using Meteor.startup as you see below. Then I'm getting all the data attributes of these `<li>`'s using data() and putting it in an object and trying to return/console.log it so I can see if it works. But I'm getting `null` as a result.

```
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    Template.messages.lists = function () {
        var allitems = lists.find();
        return allitems;
    };
    var map;
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map_canvas',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333
    });
    var lat = map.getCenter().lat();
    var lng = map.getCenter().lng();
    map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Test',
        dragend: function (e) {
            $('#lat').val(this.getPosition().lat());
            $('#lng').val(this.getPosition().lng());
        }
    });
    console.log(getMarkers());
});


function getMarkers() {
    var coordinates = {};
    coordinates = $('li.message').data();
    return coordinates;
}
```

I tried the same in my console directly and it works - I get an object back - so I'm guessing that the DOM is not ready/populated before this function is executed.

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between things like Meteor.startup and Template.mytemplate.rendered. In this case it seems that none of them works as I want?

What's the right way/place to do stuff with the DOM (traversing,getting attributes,manipulating)?

**edit**

as the code changed a lot in order to do what I wanted I post the whole thing.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var map;
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map_canvas',
    lat: 50.853642,
    lng: 4.357452
  });
  Meteor.subscribe('AllMessages', function() {
    var allitems = lists.find().fetch();
    console.log(allitems);
    allitems.forEach(function(item) { 
      var lat = item.location.lat; 
      var lng = item.location.lng;
      console.log('latitude is: ' + lat);
      console.log('longitude is: ' + lng);
      map.addMarker({ 
        lat: lat, 
        lng: lng, 
        draggable: true, 
        title: 'Test', 
        dragend: function(e) { 
          $('#lat').val(this.getPosition().lat()); 
          $('#lng').val(this.getPosition().lng()); 
        } 
      }); 
    });
  });
});
```

The above code creates a new google map (using the GMaps.js plugin) inside Meteor.Startup, and then in a nested Subscribe fetchs all documents from a collection, forEaches the results  and gets the latitude and longitude values, then goes on to add markers in the google map...

**edit 2**

I made my 'map' variable a global one this way no need to nest .subscribe and .startup. :

```
Meteor.subscribe('AllMessages', function() {
  var allitems = lists.find().fetch();
  console.log(allitems);
  allitems.forEach(function(item) { 
    var lat = item.location.lat; 
    var lng = item.location.lng;
    console.log('latitude is: ' + lat);
    console.log('longitude is: ' + lng);
    map.addMarker({ 
      lat: lat, 
      lng: lng, 
      draggable: true, 
      title: item.description, 
      dragend: function(e) { 
        $('#lat').val(this.getPosition().lat()); 
        $('#lng').val(this.getPosition().lng()); 
      } 
    }); 
  });
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map_canvas',
    lat: 50.853642,
    lng: 4.357452
  });
});

Template.messages.lists = function () {
  var allitems = lists.find().fetch();
  return allitems;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[**Meteor.startup**](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup)

`Meteor.startup()` runs only once, its run on the client and server. So when the browser loads and the initial DOM is ready or the server starts. As Sohel Khalifa said you place initialization functions here. Don't define templates in here because the the templates need to be ready before this function can be fired.

[**Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {... })**](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)

This is run when meteor has finished and rendered the DOM. Additionally is run **each** time the HTML changes within the template. So for each item in your list in a subtemplate/a change in an item/update,etc as well as the list you will see the console.log return something if you use it to check. It will return `null`/`undefined` when calling for data sometimes (which i'll explain):

**Does this mean all the DOM is ready? NO!**:

I think this is what might be causing you a bit of trouble. If you use external APIs such as Google maps, they might still render the map. the `Template.myTemplate.rendered()` means *Meteor* has finished rendering the template with the reactive variables necessary. So to find out when your Google maps might be ready you need to hook into the Google maps API. Have a [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692/how-to-check-if-google-maps-is-fully-loaded)

[**Using Meteor.subscribe**](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe)

The reason you might get `null`/`undefined` while using `rendered` is because this is the process meteor usually renders data into templates

You are basically calling `console.log(getMarkers());` before the subscription is complete, which is why you get `null`/`undefined`

Meteor uses this summarized process with templates & reactive data:

1. Build Templates with no data & render - NO data yet at this stage
2. Ask server for data in collections
3. Rebuild templates with new data & render

So if at process 1) for a very short time you will have no data yet, which is why you might get `null` (such as in your code) & at the first render. To get past this you should use `Meteor.subscribe`'s callback which is run when all the data is downloaded from the server: e.g

```
Meteor.subscribe("lists", function() {
    //Callback fired when data received
});
```

Note: Before you use this you should read the docs on using [subscriptions](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) as you need to remove the `autopublish` package, as well as make a corresponding `Meteor.publish` function on the server. While this may seem tedious you may end up doing it anyway to give your users their own lists &/or implement some kind of security.

**Suggested edits to your code:**

You are doing DOM traversing in the right place, `Template.mytemplate.onRendered(function()..` but you also need to hook into Google Maps' API to capture when their map is finished drawing. You should also use `Meteor.subscribe` to make sure you get the timing right and not get `null`/`undefined`.

Make sure you put your Template helpers in a `Meteor.isClient` but not in a `Meteor.startup` because Meteor.startup is fired after your initial DOM is ready (the intitial is the first but before its changed by reactive variables or a router) so your template definitions need to run *before* this stage.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense why I get 6 console.logs of coordinates.. because I have 6 <li>'s.. So Indeed that's a lot of executiong (considering in my final app I'll have a list of 50 items or more..)

Comment: It shouldn't really be much trouble though, getting the co-ordinates isn't that expensive an operation you could probably go with thousands but then your map would have too many pins :P

Comment: Actually instead of scanning the DOM to get data attributes, I would be better off getting the latitude and longitude directly from my Collection.. but I think that's a different question:) A question for you answer: So after all, do I put it in subscribe callback or in .rendered?:)

Comment: If you mean the getMarkers() and you're going to use the collection instead of the DOM use subscribe, it would also be less taxing if you're worried about that (such as mobile devices)

Comment: I changed my code as such: Meteor.subscribe('AllMessages', function() {
  var coordinates = {};
  coordinates = $('li.message').data();
  console.log(coordinates);  
  return coordinates;
});
but now I only get one null in the console...

Comment: But you're still using the DOM there, .data might still not be ready as rendered is called after subscribe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25895/discussion-between-george-katsanos-and-akshat)

Comment: great answer, I think rendered is onRendered now though

Comment: Is this still valid advice two years down the road? Is this still the best way to make sure the DOM has rendered?

Comment: the subscribe callback doesn't get called when in offline mode using the appcache package so need another solution to know when the collection is ready to be queried.

Comment: @malcolmhall In offline mode you wont have data, this is why it's not called back. If you're using an alternative offline data source you would have to use the callback it provides. At the moment, meteor doesn't have an official offline database.

Comment: Thanks yes I'm using GroundDB, it has a method to check if ready but it doesn't have a callback hopefully the developer will add one, I put in a request.

Comment: are all image element initialized on template rendered?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it returns `null` as a result is, you have placed it in `Meteor.startup()`. It actually  runs before the data is loaded from the server. So the `lists.find()` returns null.

The `Meteor.startup()` is a place for initializing your global variables, reative sessions and subscribing to the primary bunch of data from the server. Everything you write there will be executed once, right after the client starts up.

The `Template.myTemplate.rendered()` is a special helper provided by meteor that runs everytime when the corresponding data has changed, it is mainly used for getting attributes or manipulating DOM elements contained within that template.

So, place your helper code outside in common `isClient()` area. And use `.rendered()`helper to traverse the DOM, and getting or manipulating attributes of DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but I think now I have more questions than before:) 1)My lists.find() does work, my <li>'s are populated... (exactly as they were within .rendered ) 2)I followed your advice: I shifted all the code of getMarkers within .rendered.. Now I get 2 "null" returns and 6 console logs of the coordinates variable... Could you please post some code in your answer, that would help a lot..

Comment: One more thing, according to docs.meteor, Meteor.startup "On a client, the function will run as soon as the DOM is ready and any <body> templates from your .html files have been put on the screen." so the opposite of what you are saying..

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks Akshat for detailed answer)

I have more complicated case of using Meteor.subscribe, i have template which includes images from DB. So i need to wait for data from two collection iamges and news(all other data here).

I get my DOM ready in this way:

```
imageIsLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve){
    Meteor.subscribe('images',function(){
        resolve()
    });
});

newsIsLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve){
    Meteor.subscribe('news',function(){
        resolve()
    });
});


Template.newsList.onRendered(function(){
    Promise.all([imageIsLoaded, newsIsLoaded]).then(function() {
        // DOM IS READY!!!
        newsServices.masonryInit();
    })
});
```

Template structure:

```
<template name="newsList">
         {{#each news}}
            {{> news_item}}
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Combined with the previous responses, the promise/resolve solution that you provided fixed a problem I had with initializing dataTable before subscribe was done.

Comment: FYI I think this solution is not reactive-friendly. It works on first load, but if images or news get reactively updated (added or deleted) the plugin will not update. You will need to add a masonry refresher at the subtemplate level on the `onRendered`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to put code into Template.x.rendered() and use a Session reactive variable to track if the code has been run or not. For example, you could go about this like so:

```
Template.x.rendered = function () {
  if (Session.get('doneMarkers') == null) {
    // Do your stuff
    if (getMarkers() != null) {
      Session.set('doneMarkers', 'yes');
    }
  }
});

function getMarkers() {
  var coordinates = {};
  coordinates = $('li.message').data();
  return coordinates;
}
```

If you ever want to rerun that part of the code, you only have to call:

```
Session.set('doneMarkers', null);
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually works, although it seems it might be costly in terms of perf as the template gets re-rendered many times before everything is loaded.. (long unordered list of many many items..)