# angular-google-maps run function ONCE after initial map load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

using [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) to incorporate a google map into an app

I need a command that will run a function ONCE after initial map load is complete
- but only on the initial load, ***not after each map manipulation***

I can't use `idle` or `tilesloaded` since these are fired after every movement...

The function I want to run needs to get map bounds to pull data off a server on initial page load
- i want this to occur ONCE on initial load, then be a manual function using a refresh `map-control`
- if i use `idle` or `tilesloaded` to fire this it will pull server data *every* time a user moves the map.

Does anyone know how to fire a once off command to get map details (bounds etc) after initial map load ?

I've tried putting `maps.getBounds()` in the 2nd promise function but it doesn't work.

Note, [I've got a fiddle working here](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/5jvrxsey/) - I just can't chain any more promises after the `$scope.map` controls / options etc are defined because they don't return a promise:

The code example in the docs doesn't show how to chain a promise *after* the `$scope.map` is defined.

html

```
<div class="angular-google-map-container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="map.options" events="map.events" control="googlemap">
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

controller

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi
    .then(function(maps){
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 37.7749295, 
                longitude: -122.4194155 
            },
            zoom: 12
            events: {
                tilesloaded: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                    myServiceFuntion(maps)    // this work fine but fires every time
                },
                dragend: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                    myServiceFuntion(maps)    // this work fine but fires every time
                },
                zoom_changed: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                    myServiceFuntion(maps)    // this work fine but fires every time
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.bounds = maps.getBounds()    // this gives me 'getBounds() not a function'
        myServiceFuntion(maps);    // this gives an error... ?
        return maps;            //no promise returned here so no chance to delay the function below
    })
    .then(function(maps){
        //is this where i need to put my function ?  doesn't delay on map load since no promise returned...
    });
});
```

Obviously the `maps` object returned by the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` promise is completely different to the `maps` object returned by events like `tilesloaded` etc...  quite confusing.

Also, [the FAQ](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/faq) only indicates how to use `tilesloaded` to get the map instance - which doesn't work for reasons already described.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'correct' method I believe is to use the API `IsReady` feature by injecting the `uiGmapIsReady` service into the controller.  See [the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/IsReady).

With the `uiGmapIsReady` promise it's then possible to pass the `map` to a function / service etc with code like:

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise()                     // this gets all (ready) map instances - defaults to 1 for the first map
.then(function(instances) {                 // instances is an array object
    var maps = instances[0].map;            // if only 1 map it's found at index 0 of array
    $scope.myOnceOnlyFunction(maps);        // pass the map to your function
});
```

it's also possible to iterate through the `instances` array to run functions on each map (if you have more than one map loaded in your page):

```
uiGmapIsReady.promise()                     // this gets all (ready) map instances - defaults to 1 for the first map
.then(function(instances) {                 // instances is an array object
    angular.forEach(instances, function(value, key) {
        var maps = value.map;
        $scope.myOnceOnlyFunction(maps);    // will apply this function to each map
    });
});
```

so then the whole controller would look like

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, uiGmapIsReady) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi
    .then(function(maps){
        $scope.googlemap = {};
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 37.7749295, 
                longitude: -122.4194155 
            },
            zoom: 13,
            pan: 1,
            options: myAppServices.getMapOptions().mapOptions,
            control: {},
            events: {
                tilesloaded: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                },
                dragend: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                },
                zoom_changed: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                }
            }
        };
    });

    uiGmapIsReady.promise()                     // this gets all (ready) map instances - defaults to 1 for the first map
    .then(function(instances) {                 // instances is an array object
        var maps = instances[0].map;            // if only 1 map it's found at index 0 of array
        $scope.myOnceOnlyFunction(maps);        // this function will only be applied on initial map load (once ready)
    });

    $scope.myOnceOnlyFunction = function(maps){  // this will only be run once on initial load
        var center = maps.getCenter();           // examples of 'map' manipulation
        var lat = center.lat();
        var lng = center.lng();
        alert('I\'ll only say this once ! \n Lat : ' + lat + '\n Lng : ' + lng);
    };
});
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/comfz24o/)

---

...not sure why this isn't mentioned in the FAQ: '[How do I access the map instance?](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#faq-map-instance)' - or why using `tilesloaded` ([which is thought to be unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692/how-can-i-check-whether-google-maps-is-fully-loaded)) is suggested instead of `idle` or `uiGmapIsReady`... ?
Perhaps the FAQ question was really '***how do i access the map on a continual basis***' ?

---

Comment: uiGmapIsReady isn't working anymore, with angular 1.4.8, and angular-google-maps 2.2.1

Comment: `uiGmapIsReady` still works fine - it's just that more recent versions of `angular-google-maps` (ie since I originally posted the answer) need to have an additional plugin called `angular-simple-logger` included.  I've updated the jsfiddle to the latest versions of all code.

Comment: i've been trying to run two maps on the same page. (a big one and a small one).
I found that the above answer lead to my solution. however i had to specify the number of instances in the `promise()` like so...
`uiGmapIsReady.promise(2).then(function(instances) {...});`
without specifying the number of promises, as soon as i put a second set of html for the second map, both maps would stop rendering completely.

Answer (score 1):

As `Sal Niro` point out in another answer - one option to get around the constant calling of `tilesloaded` or `idle` is to define a variable and then mark it as true the first time the `events` functions run.

It's a bit hackish and surprising that the API has no method to access the maps object after initial map load from within the controller  ...but it works.

*However* - adding this answer since it's not practical to put your entire controller within a function (or condition) - and there are some functions you *may* want to be called continuously.  So simply define the 'run once' variable ***within your controller*** prior to your map being called.

**Solution**:
Define a variable (here arbitrarily called "initialMapLoad") set to `false` or `0` :
`var initialMapLoad = 0`

Then, within your google maps events definition (such as `tilesloaded`, `dragend` or `idle`) you can put the functions you only want to run once, within a conditional :

```
if(initialMapLoad === 0) { 
    my_single_run_function(); 
    var initialMapLoad = 1
}
```

Don't forget to redefine the `initialMapLoad` variable to `1` or `true` once your function runs.

**Example:**

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    var initialMapLoad = 0;

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi
    .then(function(maps){
        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 37.7749295, 
                longitude: -122.4194155 
            },
            zoom: 13,
            events: {
                tilesloaded: function (maps, eventName, args) {
                    // functions that run every time 
                    alert('I say this after every tile load');

                    if(initialMapLoad === 0){
                        // functions that run only once
                        alert('I only say this once' + maps.getBounds());
                        initialMapLoad = 1;
                    }
                },
            }
        };
    })
});
```

See a working example in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/ppb0oc6x/)

Comment: this is essentially the exact same answer I gave you, so I'll just delete my answer

Comment: actually it's not 'the exact same answer' - since in your answer you proposed wrapping the entire controller in a function (which is not practical for so many reasons). ...but yes the base concept of using a variable then changing to executed on first run is the same. In any case I proposed edits to your answer to make it acceptable and they were rejected by mods because it was too different - and it was suggested that I add my edits as a new answer.

Comment: I proposed wrapping your map loading code in a closure, not the entire controller. Here is the fiddle again for reference http://jsfiddle.net/f387jw61/