# How can I force Google Maps to load in my Angular app using an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-directive

I have an issue where my Google Map does not display 80% of the time. It seems to be a situation where my map has not completely rendered by the time the rest of my data has been populated in my Angular view.

**How can I force my map to load?**

I have done some research, and I have found this answer on a related questions, but I am not sure how and if I can implement something like this:

> This was bothering me for a while with GMaps v3. I found a way to do
>   it like this:
>
> ```
> google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
>     // do something only the first time the map is loaded
> });
> ```
>
> The "idle" event is triggered when the map goes to idle state -
>   everything loaded (or failed to load). I found it to be more reliable
>   then tilesloaded/bounds_changed and using addListenerOnce method the
>   code in the closure is executed the first time "idle" is fired and
>   then the event is detached.
>
> Link: [How can I check whether Google Maps is fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832692/how-can-i-check-whether-google-maps-is-fully-loaded)

**This is my current setup:**

**1. My Google Maps API link and key is in my index.html file:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

**2. I use the following as my Angular Directive:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .directive('ogGoogleMap', function ($http, $q) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              twitter: '=',
              instagram: '='
          },
          template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
          replace: true,
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

              var map, infoWindow;
              var markers = [];

              // map config
              var mapOptions = {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-0.013026, 21.333860),
                  zoom: 3,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

              // init the map
              function initMap() {
                  if (map === void 0) {
                      map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);
                  }
              }

              // place a marker
              function setMarker(map, position, title, content, icon) {

                  if (icon === 'IN') {
                      icon = 'images/instagramMarker.png';
                  }
                  else {
                      icon = 'images/twitterMarker.png';
                  }

                  var marker;
                  var markerOptions = {
                      position: position,
                      map: map,
                      title: title,
                      icon: icon
                  };

                  marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
                  markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                      // close window if not undefined
                      if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                          infoWindow.close();
                      }
                      // create new window
                      var infoWindowOptions = {
                          content: content
                      };
                      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
              }

              function deleteCurrentMarkers() {
                  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                      markers[i].setMap(null);
                  }
                  markers = [];
              }

              scope.$watch('instagram', function () {
                  deleteCurrentMarkers();
                  populateMarkers(scope.twitter, 'TW');
                  populateMarkers(scope.instagram, 'IN');
              });

              // show the map and place some markers
              initMap();

              function populateMarkers(locationArray, type) {

                  angular.forEach(locationArray, function (location) {

                      setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]), '', '', type);

                  });

              }

          }
      };
  });
```

**3. I use the following simple method of assigning my map data in my Angular Controller:**

**First I retrieve my data:**

```
function pullSocialData() {

    SocialMediaUserService.getKeywordProfileID().then(function (keywordProfileID) {

        GetFusionDataService.getItems(getRequestURL(keywordProfileID))
          .success(function (data) {

              formatDataAccordingToLocation(data);

          })
          .error(function (error, status) {
              handleDataRetrievalError(error, status);
          });

    });
}
```

**The I assign my data:**

```
function formatDataAccordingToLocation(data) {
    $scope.twitterLocations = data.lat_longs_twitter;
    $scope.instagramLocations = data.lat_longs_instagram;
}
```

**This is what my data from the API looks like:**

```
lat_longs_twitter: [
    [
    -25.77109,
    28.09264
    ],
    [
    -26.1078272,
    28.2229014
    ]
]
```

**4. My HTML map div:**

```
<div ng-show="!demographics.showDemographicsGraph">
    <og-google-map twitter="twitterLocations" instagram="instagramLocations"></og-google-map>
</div>
```

When my map loads properly, it looks like this:

[image]

When it doesn't load properly it looks like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would call `initMap()` inside the map load callback so you know that it has been properly loaded

Comment: @Dario May I ask that you perhaps clarify or give an example? I am not too sure from where to call the `initMap()` method. I have added all aspects related to the maps to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive link function, try to move `initMap` inside the map `idle` callback:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){ 
   // show the map and place some markers
   initMap();
});
```

Comment: I think I might be doing something wrong. I have inserted the map `idle` callback in a number of places in my link function, and put breakpoints on each `initMap()` call in these callbacks, but the breakpoints are never hit. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of google map are you using? Try to use `google.maps.event.addListener` (without `Once`)

Comment: Just some feedback; I have tried a number of different proposed solutions, but none worked. I always got the same result; whatever i used as validation, equated to true, and the script would run and the map didn't load. I tried `if (google && google.maps)`, I tried `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function (){}`, I tried `if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object'){}`, `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function (){}` and some other variations. I finally got it to work, by making the following change in `scope.$watch` *see answer

Answer (score 0):

To make my map load, I added some validation to check whether my data has returned before initializing the map. I also added a `timeOut` for good measure, to give the map more time to render.

**I made the following change in my Angular Directive:**

```
scope.$watch('instagram', function () {
  if (scope.twitter != undefined || scope.instagram != undefined) {
      initMap();
      setTimeout(function () {
          deleteCurrentMarkers();
          populateMarkers(scope.twitter, 'TW');
          populateMarkers(scope.instagram, 'IN');
      }, 3000);
  }
});
```