# Google Maps iframe - automatically make left locations menu visible on load

Tags: google-maps

I have a div that slides down on click to reveal an iframe Google map. However, I would like the left locations side menu to automatically be visible when the map is loaded. I have tried a few things but no luck whatsoever.

[Here is a screenshot](https://drive.google.com/a/wrladv.com/file/d/0Bwg09e5tsrJaV0FEWFo3Y2NmclU/view?usp=drivesdk) to the map of mine. I have purposely hidden the locations for client privacy.

Is there a parameter that I can pass in the URL to make this happen or maybe a piece of jQuery that will make the menu pop out on map load?

Comment: Have you tried hooking into the Google Map event when the map is loaded? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262773/8375199) answer, which explains the event. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) is the API's list of events.

Comment: Sounds like you would like to load Google MyMaps via API. This was requested in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820262. However, Google rejected this feature request and marked it as Infeasible.